# gremlin "where" condition how support constant value

Tags: gremlin

i want to write a gremlin script,like this:

```
g.V().out().as('a').[many code].as('b')

.where('a',eq('b').or(eq('a_constant_string'))).by('name')
```

but a_constant_string is a string constant ,not a vertex or edge
if writing like this,will thrown Exception:
**org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ResponseException: Neither the sideEffects, map, nor path has a a_constant_string-key**

how to write

Answer (score 0):

When you use `where()` that way you put the predicate `eq()` into a mode where it is dealing with labels only so you can't inject a constant in there. In this case, I'd think the easiest thing to do would be to move the "or" outside of the `where()`:

```
g.V().
  out().as('a').as('b').
  or(where('a', eq('b')).by('name'),
     has('name', 'a_constant_string'))
```